# Exporting form blender to unity

Tags: export, unity

I am having trouble with exporting a simple "map" from blender into unity. I have tried to export it as a .fbx file, but that doesn't help me that much as it gives me what looks like an incomplete mesh, but yet it is there. I used a plane mesh to make this asset, but I am not sure that the problem

I was wondering if anyone was having this problem as well and could help me quickly

Any help is very appreciated,[image]

thank you.

(btw I am using blender 2.8)

Comment: Looks like inverted normals to me. Have you tried recalculating or flipping the normals?

Comment: No i havent, i will look on how to do that now and will report back.

Comment: perfect, it seems to have been fixed. Like you said I just had to recalculate the inside and outside normals and all looks fine now. Thank you, Robert!

Comment: @RobertGützkow could you add this as anwser? so that it is clear that there is a solution to the question? :-)

Answer (score 2):

The normals on your mesh are inverted. The effect you're seeing is caused by backface culling in the game engine, where faces with normals pointing in the opposite direction of the camera aren't rendered.

In order to fix this, you can try to recalculate the normals to face outside by using *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside* or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>. If they are consistently flipped in the wrong direction you can also use *Mesh > Normals > Flip*.

Blender has helpful options in the *Viewport Overlay* settings for detecting inverted normals. While in edit mode, you can display the normals. This allows you to easily see when the normals of your entire mesh have been inverted.

[image: Normal direction]

Sometimes only a few faces may have inverted normals. These can be quickly spotted by enabling the *Face Orientation* option.

[image: Face orientation]